# How do I read MIDI files using MIPS?

Tags: assembly, mips, mars-simulator

With all the advice that've been given, I've tried to make a program that plays a simple piano scale, so far I've got this:

```
.data
    pitchC: .byte 60
    pitchD: .byte 62
    pitchE: .byte 64
    pitchF: .byte 65
    pitchG: .byte 67
    pitchA: .byte 69
    pitchB: .byte 71
    instrument: .byte 14
    volume: .byte 127
    duration: .byte 100
.text
main:
    addi $t0, $zero, 0
    while:
        bgt $t0, 7, exit
        li $v0, 31
        la $a0, pitchA
        la $a1, duration
        la $a2, instrument
        la $a3, volume
        syscall

        addi $t0, $t0, 1

        j while 
    exit:
        li $v0, 10
        syscall
```

It is playing a note, but if I try to add another note with a different pitch to play after the first one it won't play, and if I change any value like the volume/instrument/durantion it won't affect the sound. What could be causing this?

Comment: MIPS is but a CPU, it doesn't read files or play music. What's the platform/device?

Comment: Oh my bad, you're right. I'm using MARS.

Comment: You load pitch without taking t0 into account: `la $a0, pitchA`. Also, `la` loads the address of the variable, not the content. You want `lb`.

Comment: It is now done! Thank you for the tips :)

Comment: We say thanks around here by upvoting and/or accepting the answer. :)

Comment: Even thought the original question is now solved, if it's possible to answer a new question, what's the best way to force the program to close by pressing a key? I would create a new thread but I got negative feedback on this one, so only tomorrow.

Comment: With the "Keyboard and display" tool running, there's a magical memory location 0xffff0000. If you read the word from there, and the low bit is set, that means a key was just pressed. That's your exit condition. If you run without the keyboard tool, keystrokes in the MARS' Run I/O area won't be detected (and the interrupts won't be generated either).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's all in the syscalls. Open a file using service #13, read using #14, play MIDI notes using either #31 (async) or #33 (sync). You are on your own, though, when it comes to parsing the MIDI file format. MIDI syscalls take pitch, duration, volume, and instrument. MIDI files encode those. [The spec is available.](https://www.midi.org/specifications/item/the-midi-1-0-specification)

You can use syscalls #30 (time) and/or #32 (sleep) to control the note timing.

[Syscall reference with samples is also available.](https://courses.missouristate.edu/KenVollmar/MARS/Help/SyscallHelp.html)

---

Although, if you want to **just play the basic scale**, like you write, you don't need to read any MIDI files. Just use syscall #33 in a loop by pitch. For a C major scale, the note numbers (which correspond to `$a0` in the syscall) won't be contiguous; they'd go 60,62,64,65,67,69,71,72. So you'll need either a conditional increment, or an array of note numbers. Switching to a minor scale would be an exercise for the musically inclined :)

---

EDIT re: keypress reaction. It's possible, but only with some help from MARS' optional tools. When the "Keyboard and display MMIO Simulator" tool is running and connected to the execution (click "Connect to MIPS"), there's a magical memory location 0xffff0000. If you read the word at that address, and the lowest bit is set, that means a key was just pressed. The very act of reading clears the bit; it's not a traditional memory variable.

If you run without the keyboard tool, keystrokes in the MARS' "Run I/O" area won't be detected (and the interrupts won't be generated either). That area is logically a console, not a keyboard. The "read character" syscall (#14) blocks the execution until a character is typed; that's not a good fit for a program that does something (e. g. plays music) while watching for keystrokes.

---

For completeness' sake, with the keyboard tool, you can also use an interrupt handler to capture keypresses. You can use syscalls from the interrupt, so if you want a keypress to terminate the program, that's all your handler should do - call the exit (#10) syscall.

To hook up the keyboard interrupt, you have to write an interrupt handler and place it at the fixed address 0x80000180 by declaring a kernel code section: `.ktext 0x80000180`. Then, somewhere in the beginning of the program, you have to enable the keyboard interrupt by setting the 1st bit in the Receiver Control register at 0xffff0000 to 1.

In a properly written handler, you have to retrieve and interrogate the interrupt cause register (coprocessor 0 register $13) to tell keyboard interrupts from other interrupts, exceptions, and traps. However, in the kind of programs that are usually written for MARS (i. e. learning exercises), **the keyboard interrupt might be the only one one would ever encounter**. As of this writing, the keyboard tool is the only possible source of interrupts (keyboard and display) on MARS, and the display interrupt is disabled by default. If you don't explicitly use trap commands, traps won't happen either. As for exceptions, those are bad news anyway, and probably should serve as an exit condition too. Graceful recovery and continuation after an exception is possible, but it's deep magic that is unlikely to appear in a MARS program.

What I'm saying here, an interrupt handler that does nothing but exit immediately might just be all the handling the you need.

In the handler, use the $k0/$k1 registers to store intermediate values, they are specifically reserved for the kernel.

Comment: It's not my first ever MARS program, but it is my first if we're talking about difficulty/dimension of the problem. It's for a university final project but we've been doing easier programs. Those links you've shared are really useful, I think I've find somewhat of a start, thanks!

Comment: Good. Well then, maybe start with a program that plays the scale. It's syscall 33 in a loop.